# Custom /Page/2/ Template Only

Tags: templates, sidebar

Is there a method of doing this?  Can I use PHP to say `if(URL=page/2/) { }` or something like that within my template?

Essentially, I want an ad to appear in my sidebar when a user clicks 'Older Entries' and Wordpress directs them to "myblog.com/page/2/".

I'm pretty sure I know how to accomplish this with JQuery, but I was wondering if there was a way through PHP, and without a plugin.

Thanks WPA

Comment: So you want to hardcode every exception? Sorry, this is bad style. If I were you, I'd write a small plugin that uses custom fields to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has the [`$_SERVER[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable, you can use this to get just about anything contained in the URL, you'll probably want to look at `PATH_INFO` as a launching point. You can use `strpos()` (or, if you want to have better results, `preg_match()`) to check whether or not the string you get from `$_SERVER[]` contains the desired string.

Comment: This is way too low-level.

Comment: I agree that it's not the best method, but it answers exactly what the OP asked for, specifically a PHP only solution for checking the url for the paged parameter.

Comment: Why not propose the best method? ;) The problem with your solution (besides all matters of style) is that it assumes a specific URL format. Even if pretty URL format never changes, access via ugly URLs is always possible and has to be dealt with specifically if you do it like you propose.

Comment: Yes, but yours does not stick to the question. Agree to disagree.

Comment: All I see is one person used template tags provided by The Loop, and one person used plain PHP and was more courteous.  Gets the rep...

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [`is_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) to identify the page, for example like that:

```
if ( is_page('mypage') ) { ... }
```

The function apparently accepts page IDs, titles and slugs.

Note the documentation about its behaviour w.r.t The Loop.

In order to check the page number, use [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_paginated_Pages):

```
$paged = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
if ( !empty($paged) && $paged >= 2 ) { ... }
```